# What is Chazakah from 3 Times action

Tags: halacha, torah-study, mitzvah, torah-reading, nedarim-shevuot

Hi I want to know what does it really mean a chazakah that gets formed after 3 actions and is it a sin of you don't do that same action the 4th time and what is the source of this law and how far does it go? Like if you breath constantly and when you leave this world does that mean there going to make you do Hatarat nedarim? Also when we were in Egypt we were there more than three days so does that mean we had to do Hatarat nedarim before we left? Also is a chazakah considered a neder or Shevuah?